# How to get this type of time format "Aug. 13, 2014, 4:04 p.m." using strftime?

Tags: python, django

I need to get "Aug. 13, 2014, 4:04 p.m." time format using python datetime object, How to get this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using the Django date formatting language or `datetime.strftime()`? What part of the [`strftime` formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) isn't clear or doesn't give you exactly what you wanted?

Comment: Handy reference: [strftime.org](http://strftime.org)

Comment: when I try to render datetime obj in django template it gives me above format, Now I want get the same format by using strftime, I am searching for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-format
tag similar to 'N' described in link (it gives '.' after the month if month name more than 4 chars)

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Is there any smililar format charcter as 'N' in strftime ?? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh that rocks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, this solves my problem

```
from django.utils.dateformat import DateFormat
DateFormat(datetime.datetime.now()).format('N j, Y, P')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now.strftime('%b. %m, %Y, %I:%m %p')
```